# mocha share variables between files

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to wire the objects between 2 mocha test files. Here is my test1.js file which should export a variable once all the test cases are executed.

```
var assert = require('assert');


var newUser = {
    email: "test@ex.com",
    name: "test@ex.com",
    password: "test@ex.com",
    confirmPassword: "test@ex.com"
}


var studentAcademicData = {
    marks: {},
    activities: {}
}

var studentInterests = []

var testSummary = {},
    loggedInUser = {},
    avaialbleAssessment = {},
    test = {},
    interests = {};

var studentAcademicId, studentId, academicYearId, assessmentId, testId;



describe('perform functional Test', function() {

    before(function() {
        this.timeout(15000);
        db.init(config.mongodb);
    })

    //Register a student    it ('Register a student', function(done){

    StudentController.register(newUser).then(function(data) {
        assert.equal(data.name, newUser.name) assert.equal(data.tenant, newUser.tenant) assert.equal(data.customerType, newUser.customerType)

        done();
    }).catch(done)
});

//User authentication   it ('Authenticates user', function(done){


var userInfo = {
    appId: "abc",
    email: newUser.email,
    password: newUser.password
}

security.userAuthenticate(userInfo).then(function(data) {

securityToken = data.securityToken;
tenantId = data.tenantId;
emailStatus = data.emailStatus;
mobileStatus = data.mobileStatus studentId = data.userId;

done();
}).catch(done)
});


it('Gets Student by id', function(done) {

StudentController.getById(studentId).then(function(data) {

    loggedInUser = data;
    loggedInUser.tenantId = 'abc';
    loggedInUser.userId = studentId;
    loggedInUser.securityToken = securityToken;

    done();
}).catch(done)
});

})

module.exports.testUser = {
    loggedInUser: loggedInUser,
    avaialbleAssessment: avaialbleAssessment,
    interests: interests,
    testSummary: testSummary,
    studentAcademicData: studentAcademicData,
    newUs
    er: newUser,
    test: test
};
```

Here is my test2.file which imports the object from test1.js file

```
var assert = require('assert');
var rewire = require('rewire');

var TestUserObj = require('./test1');


describe('perform test2 Test', function() {

    console.log("in test2")

    console.log("TestUserObj ::::" + JSON.stringify(TestUserObj))

});
```

The output i get in test2.js file is

```
TestUserObj

    ::::{
        "testUser": {
            "loggedInUser": {},
            "avaialbleAssessment": {},
            "interests": {},
            "testSummary": {},
            "newUser": {
                email: "test@ex.com",
                name: "test@ex.com",
                password: "test@ex.com",
                confirmPassword: "test@ex.com"
            },
            "test": {}
        }
    }
```

the exported values does not not contain the modified objects

Comment: the require will just load the file, not execute the functions inside

Comment: is there any way i can share the variables between 2 files in mocha?? I want to run test1.js file first. Whatever the output i get i want to export it and use it someother files.

Comment: i don't know if it's possible. But anyway, I think it's a bad practice to do it. Every test file should be run separately.

Answer (score 2):

As @sheplu mentioned above in the comments, test files in unit testing should be separate. In fact, each individual unit being tested should be independent of other units.

What you are looking for in your case, is a `buildup` and `teardown` system, or [`fixtures`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Software).

Basically, you need to make sure that you have the required items already set up before you run a set of tests.

### For this you can look into the following:

#### Buildup phase:

- Create a set of dummy data, and quickly seed it into your database
- Implement a way to simulate logged in user
- Make use of Mocha's `before()` and/or `beforeEach()` [hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) to do this
- If you are using MongoDB with mongoose, [`mockgoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockgoose) provides an excellent package to simulate a test database in memory

#### Teardown phase:

After test cases are done, you should also take care to:

- Log out the user
- Remove the data from db
- Use Mocha's `after()` and/or `afterEach()` [hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks)

You can also check out [`supertest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) to make API request calls in test cases.

Doing the above in your second file would ensure that you always have a working set of data to run your tests with, within specific test suite.