# Trying to export global variables in mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, global-variables, chai

i'm trying to test all the way of my api with mocha but when i trying to export the userId (user i'm created in post) to try to get he in get(another folder) my user_id come undefined

Here an example:

```
var userId

describe('POST TESTS', () => {
it("POST User", (done) => {

    var user = {
        name: "Pedro",
        email: "xxxx@gamer.com"
    }

    chai.request(server)
    .post('/register/user')
    .send(user)
    .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200)
        
        res.body.id.should.be.a("number")
        
        userId = res.body.id
        
        done()
    })


 
})})   

module.exports = userId
```

And when i try to log this in another file or even before module.exports, userId is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811000/mocha-share-variables-between-files)

The variable will not be updated, so the second test will get the initial value. Which in this case is `undefined` because is not initialized.